Get icons from X apps that don't have _NET_WM_ICON property set
I'm trying to extract the icon from an xwindow, namely the one from Obsidian which doesn't seem to have the _NET_WM_ICON property set. How can I still extract this icon information? Is there another way? I'm using python-xlib right now.

you can try to get XWMHints, it has a member named icon_pixmap. and you can try to find icon file too, detail:
specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html
My WM have 3 ways to get icon, detail:
https://sourceforge.net/p/gsmwm/code/ci/master/tree/src/image.c
